# In which countries can I fly an FAA compliant Part 103 ultralight?

Tags: ultralight, aircraft-certification

İf I have a legal part 103 ultralight as defined by the FAA, in which countries may I fly this ultralight in the world in addition to the USA?

Comment: There's no such thing as an FAA certified Part 103 ultralight. The FAA does not issue certificates for Part 103 ultralights.

Comment: I removed the "certificate" part of the question so it now makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you asking if there are other countries that will let you fly a part 103 ultralight under the FAA's rules, i.e. no registration, no training, no pilot's certificate? Or are you asking if other countries will let you fly it under *their* rules, which might include registration and a pilot's certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Although the formula for compliance is [somewhat different](https://www.tc.gc.ca/en/services/aviation/registering-leasing-aircraft/register-aircraft/register-basic-ultra-light-aeroplane.html), in general you can fly an ultralight that is compliant with FAR 103 in Canada as a Basic Ultralight.  The major difference is it has to be registered (not certified in any way, just registered with call letters), and you need an Ultralight Pilot Permit to fly it.